# Raspberry Pi 2, Windows 10 IoT Core, 433Mhz Transciever

Tags: rpi.gpio, windows-iot

Anyone had any success receiving RF signals with any circuit board transceiver (like NRF24L01, RF1100SE, CC1101, etc) on a rPi2 with Windows 10 IoT Core?

I had this working fine on rPi/python, but now looking for a C# solution.

I can wire it up as shown in other RF rPi blogs. Without a handy library, I appreciate I'd have to buffer and "Manchester decode" the signal, but I am unsure how to adapt the "SpiDevice" temperature and potentiometer samples (https://github.com/ms-iot/samples
). I am not getting anything out of the readBuffer.

If there is a simple C++ library anyone knows (that I can include in my Universal c# App on Windows 10 IoT Core) which handles RF comms, that would be even better.

I have trawled the interweb, any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Not promising it will get you an answer, but seeking for help with problems like this will usually benefit from an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) -- otherwise you are asking people who do not know you to believe the fact that you are "not getting anything out of the readBuffer" is something other than a simple mistake by you, and risk wasting there own time only to have it end in, "Oh whoops, nevermind...my bad".